# How to make static IP address dynamic

Tags: ip, isp

My ISP gave me static IP Address. Is there a way that I can make this static IP Address dynamic? Perhaps using either proxy or any other application?

Comment: You could just use DHCP in the WAN settings of your router. Why would you need special software to do this? You either use the static IP or you don't.

Comment: Also, why do you want to try to use a dynamic IP?  Dynamic IPs are more a convenience for ISPs, you shouldn't see any difference.  In fact many ISP will assign the same "dynamic" IP address to the same machine if it remains on the network after the lease expires, so it is very similar to having a static IP.

Comment: @Moses He's not talking about home network IP. He uses the word `ISP` Internet service provider. He's talking about his public IP, which he can't change when the ISP doesn't want to

Comment: @nixda If your ISP gives you a static IP, you have the option of using the static IP or using one that is randomly assigned from DHCP. At least that's the way it works in 99% of the United States.

Comment: @Moses Well, in my country there are some ISP which don't give you that option

Comment: @Navneil - Contact your service provider and request a dynamic ip address.  There is **nothing** you can do to be assigned a dynamic ip address if your service provider is assigning you a static ip address.

Comment: Could you please explain why do you want to have a dynamic IP address? It is possible that having a dynamic IP address is not a best solution for your problem. -- Do you want to change your IP address because of some limitations imposed on it by certain internet services?

Answer (score 7):

You need to contact your ISP. Static and Dynamic IPs are controlled by the person providing the IP, and you'll need to be switched over by them.